# DNS propogation is not complete

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, ns-record

I pointed my domain bought on reg.com to Hostinger 4 days ago.
But my DNS propogation is still not completed. NS records have a few location to propgate, and Cname is not propogated at all.
What should I do?

Any advice is appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance!

Here is the screenshot of NS records propogation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AavdF.jpg)

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/wisdom-in-your-mind.com

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! While your question may technically be on-topic for Server Fault, it will likely get better attention and thus better answers in a different SE site, such as [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What's not propagated? A CNAME record on apex is technically not allowed. The A-record looks fine. Show us what the zone file *should* look like, and pinpoint what's not propagating.

Comment: Added screenshot with what's not propagating

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. What does a lookup return, and what *should* it return?

Comment: I don't know anything about your technical terms :) I've been told I have to get all the locations propagated, and I see some issues with that, this is why I ask for your advice

Comment: There is no DNS propagation, this is a myth. If you query your authoritative nameservers the changes can be seen immediately. If not, ask your DNS provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see your DNS is now managed by Hostinger's servers (ns1.dns-parking.com and ns2.dns-parking.com). Any CNAMEs etc which you might have set up on reg.com before you pointed the DNS to Hostinger will have been lost, and you will need to redo them in Hostinger's DNS zone-editor (https://hpanel.hostinger.com/hosting/(your-domain-name)/advanced/dns-zone-editor). Not sure why you need a CNAME, but the A record has sucesfully propogated:  https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/wisdom-in-your-mind.com